# JQuery Help with Hover/Fade/Animate Image

Tags: jquery, hover, jquery-animate, fade

I would like to create a javascript/jquery so that when I hover an

item, 2 or 3 classes are called as a hovering image, since there will be a "left", "middle", and "right" image. The left and right will be fixed width, but the middle must grow according to the size of the remaining width.

I tried using the lavalamp effect, however it looks weird stopping the movement functionality, but thats all I could think of/achieve. However then I came across another problem, one that I would like the 'hover' image to fadeIn and fadeOut.

You could take a look at this menu, its what I achieved so far - http://valkesh.000space.com

Basically the code is the following-

```
<style type="text/css">
ul.nav { list-style:none;  overflow:hidden;  }
ul.nav li { float:left; height:39px; background-color:#666666;  padding:0 5px;  }
ul.nav li.last { -moz-border-radius-topright:9px; -webkit-border-top-right-radius:9px; 
-moz-border-radius-bottomright:9px; -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius:9px;
}
ul.nav li.bg { margin:7px 0px 0px 3px; padding-right:8px; position:absolute; z-index:50; left:155px; width:60px; background:url(bg-right.png) no-repeat right top; }
ul.nav li .left{ background:url(bg.png) no-repeat left top; height:39px;  }
ul.nav li a {padding:8px 20px;  color:#000000; font-size:18px; font-weight:bold; display:block; text-decoration:none; z-index:100; position:relative; }

</style>

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.easing.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
{
   $('#nav1 li.bg').css({opacity: 0, visibility: "visible"});   

    $('#nav1 li a').hover(function()
    {
        var offset=$(this).offset();
        var thiswidth =$(this).width()+13;
        $('#nav1 li.bg').stop().animate({left:offset.left+"px",width:thiswidth+"px"},100);  
        $('#nav1 li.bg').css({opacity: 0, visibility: "visible"}).animate({opacity: 100});   
    },
    function()
    {
        $('#nav1 li.bg').stop().animate({left:"155px",width:"60px"},100); 
        $('#nav1 li.bg').css({opacity: 0, visibility: "visible"});   
    });    
});
</script>
<body>

<div class="menucontainer" style="margin-top:15px;">
   <ul class="nav" id="nav1">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>   
        <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li> 
        <li class="bg"><div class="left"></div></li>    
   </ul>
</div>
</body>
```

I would appreciate if anyone can guide me into at least doing the hover with 2 or 3 images

Thanks

Comment: I'm finding it difficult to understand exactly what effect you're looking for. Could you offer any further clarification?

Comment: Basically I have a menu, with 'li' items of flexible widths (I wont know these width's beforehand) therefore on hover of these 'li' items I want the hover image to be split into 3 classes. A 'left' image covering the first 5px, a 'Right' image covering the last 5px, and the 'Middle' image which will grow according to the remaining width of the 'li'

The problem I am having is that I can only get it to work with one static image, but lets say if the first 'li' has a width 100px, and the second 'li' has a width 150px, the hover image can't be a static width.

Hope this helps

Thanks

Comment: Just to add to my previous comment, the width of Home and the width of Contact Us, arent the same, hence I would like the images to grow accordingly to their width (which I won't know, since the Text for the menu is generated by the software at runtime for the user)

Then I would like the hover image (the blue'ish round button shown on my site given in my first post) to fadeIn and fadeOut rather than making the hover effect static

Comment: Are you trying to use multiple background images?

Comment: Basically yes, multiple background images (3 images) for a single hover... as i said, the Left image, Middle image and Right image... 

is it possible to load 3 classes (1 class for each image) into 1 hover event ?

Comment: Unfortunately you cannot use multiple background images. You can use a repeating image however so its only the ends that may give a problem. Another option is to not use the background image but use a div that is positioned over the element containg the 3 images.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code out as I think I got it to do what you wanted. I pulled out your fadeIn and fadeOut animations and put them into a separate hover (for the `<ul>`). I didn't touch the CSS or the HTML.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#nav1 li.bg').css({opacity: 0, visibility: "visible"});

 $('#nav1').hover(function(){
  $('#nav1 li.bg').animate({opacity: 1, visibility: "visible"},400);
 }, function(){
  $('#nav1 li.bg').animate({opacity: 0, visibility: "hidden"},400);
 })
 $('#nav1 li a').hover(function(){
  var offset=$(this).offset();
  var thiswidth =$(this).width()+13;
  $('#nav1 li.bg').animate({left:offset.left+"px",width:thiswidth+"px"},100);
 }, function(){
  $('#nav1 li.bg').animate({left:offset.left+"px",width:"60px"},100);       
 });
})
```